# How to run docker-build.sh file in ubuntu?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-build

I run below below command in terminal but i get command not found .

[image: this is image of my problem :]

and my code is :

[image]

Notice : i have used `chmod +x ...` but it is not problem

Comment: change the pictures by code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` in front of your variables when you set them, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=0.0.1
ARCH=alrz
APP=vehicle-color-recognition
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" > /dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
docker build -f $DIR/Dockerfile -t $ARCH/$APP:$VERSION .
```

Comment: Thanks , How about ps1 files , Should I  remove $ in this format of files ?